# Move Onprem files to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Daily files need to be send to AWS S3 and then the compute will be done by a batch process running at a specific time in EKS. Please suggest how we can send files securely to S3

Also, every PUT will create a new object in S3 so I am thinking of having a trigger after the file is loaded with the object link and save it to DynamoDB.

The process will wake up as per its schedule and look into the DynamoDB to figure out the correct S3 object to process.

Please suggest any better approach

Answer (score 0):

- You can setup simple cron job to send the files to S3 after desirable interval.
- AWS SDK for S3 supports ssl (which in transit) which you can use to securely
  transfer files.
- You can send batch put request if needed.
- Create a user specific for this person and give it only programmatic access to assume role with required permissions to get the temporary credentials in on-premise script.